# Javascript stopwatch ignores the stopped time when the page reloads / refreshes though the timer was stopped / paused

Tags: javascript, stopwatch

I am building a stopwatch using Javascript to get the time duration of a task. The stopwatch works perfectly; but there is an issue came up ! The issue is, the stopwatch is ignoring the stopped / paused time while page reloads though it was stopped / paused by "stop_btn".

**The Javascript :**

```
var timer;
var startTime;
var isRunning = false;
var waitedTime = 0;
var stoppedTime = 0;

function start() {
  if (isRunning) return;
  isRunning = true;
  startTime = parseInt(localStorage.getItem('startTime') || Date.now());
  if (timer) {
    waitedTime += (Date.now() - stoppedTime);
  }
  localStorage.setItem('startTime', startTime);
  timer = setInterval(clockTick, 100);
}

function stop() {
  isRunning = false;
  clearInterval(timer);
  stoppedTime = Date.now();
}

function reset() {
  isRunning = false;
  stoppedTime = 0;
  waitedTime = 0;

  clearInterval(timer);
  timer = undefined;
  localStorage.removeItem('startTime');
  document.getElementById('display-area').innerHTML = "00:00:00.000";
}

function clockTick() {
  var currentTime = Date.now(),
    timeElapsed = new Date(currentTime - startTime - waitedTime),
    hours = timeElapsed.getUTCHours(),
    mins = timeElapsed.getUTCMinutes(),
    secs = timeElapsed.getUTCSeconds(),
    ms = timeElapsed.getUTCMilliseconds(),
    display = document.getElementById("display-area");

  display.innerHTML =
    (hours > 9 ? hours : "0" + hours) + ":" +
    (mins > 9 ? mins : "0" + mins) + ":" +
    (secs > 9 ? secs : "0" + secs) + "." +
    (ms > 99 ? ms : ms > 9 ? "0" + ms : "00" + ms);
};

var stopBtn = document.getElementById('stop_btn');
var startBtn = document.getElementById('start_btn');
var resetBtn = document.getElementById('reset_btn');

stopBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  stop();
});
startBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  start();
});
resetBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  reset();
})
start();
```

**Working fiddle :** [https://jsfiddle.net/2x5L8tqs/2/](https://jsfiddle.net/DevJr/0Lwfbyzg/4/)

**The solution I've tried:**

I understand that the problem with the Script is while the page reloads the waitedTime and stoppedTime both become zero.

```
var waitedTime = 0;
var stoppedTime = 0;
```

So I've tried to store the exact stopped / paused time in the stop function like this:

```
function stop() {

        isRunning = false;
        clearInterval(timer);
        stoppedTime = Date.now();
        localStorage.setItem('stoppedTime', Date.now());
    }
```

And again called the stored stopped time from the localStorage on the top like this:

```
var timer;
var startTime;
var isRunning = false;
var waitedTime = 0;
var stoppedTime = 0;

if (localStorage.getItem('stoppedTime') === null) {

} else {
    
    stoppedTime = parseInt(localStorage.getItem('stoppedTime'));
    localStorage.setItem('stoppedTime', stoppedTime);
}
```

Theoretically, that should work since the waited time will receive the stopped time and start the timer exactly from the stopped time. But exactly nothing happens/changes !
Can anyone  help please with the issue?

**Tried solution fiddle :** https://jsfiddle.net/DevJr/0Lwfbyzg/4/

Comment: `localStorage['stoppedTime']`, `localStorage['stoppedtime']` and `localStorage[stoppedTime]` are three different values (or more since the last one will be a different number as name every time). Check it in the devtools to see what happens. Just use `'stoppedTime'` everywhere and you'll be fine. By the way you would probably have noticed that something is off there if you had single-stepped through your code as the page loads and checked the values loaded. I can't stress enough how valuable the devtools will be once you got accustomed to using them!

Comment: I've solved the variable name issue here and in the fiddle too. But nothing changes !

Comment: I still see you referencing the _content of the variable_ `stoppedTime` (which will be a number) as name, instead of the _string_ `'stoppedTime'`... Did you check it in the devtools as I suggested?

Comment: I've checked again and edited by scripts. And also checked in devtools ; there is no error or issue showing too. But the issue remains unsolved. The timer always restarting by skipping the waitedTime ! What to do ?

Comment: When I said check devtools I didn't mean look for errors but actually inspect what is happening. Please debug your code. Step through each line, check what variables are accessed, what their value is, how it behaves (you can also see the contents of localStorage in the "Application" tab), and compare every step it takes to your expectations. If it does something unexpected, you found an issue, then you can try to understand why it happens.